# Probability of hitting the “bullseye”

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve this task but I'm obviously stuck. Will anyone help me solve it?

> John is throwing darts at a target. He is very good at the game, so
> the chances of him hitting the “bullseye” (i.e. the center) are $25$%.
> It is reasonable to assume that individual attempts are independent.
> If he throws $5$ times in total, what is the probability that he will
> hit the bullseye:
> a) Exactly three times
> b) At least three times

Comment: This represents a binomial distribution, with probability of hitting $k$ targets given by $${5\choose k} (0.25)^k (0.75)^{5-k}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a binomial distribution since these are independent Bernoulli trials so a trial outcome is either success (hitting the bullseye) or failure and you want the probability of getting a certain number of successes in a certain number of trials regardless of where they happen.

In Bionmial distribution $P(X=k)$ is of the form:

$\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$

Where:

$p$ is the probability of success
$n$ is the total number of trials
$k$ is the number of successes

The general formula for your question would be:

$\binom{5}{k}\cdot (0.25)^k \cdot (0.75)^{5-k}$
For your first question we get:
$\binom{5}{3}\cdot (0.25)^3 \cdot (0.75)^{2}$

For your second question they are asking for the probability that AT LEAST $3$ successes so that is the probability of getting three successes+ the probability of getting four successes+ probability of getting four successes, we get the following sum:

$\sum_{k=3}^5 \binom{5}{k}\cdot (0.25)^k \cdot (0.75)^{5-k}$

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is very useful! I try to apply this with your equation and results are a) 0.014648  b) 0.11718 .But this results are little bit different then results from my task where I need to have results a) 0.08789 b) 0.1035. Now I wonder where I made a mistake?

Comment: I think you made a calculation error, for example the second part gives $0.1035$, check https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%5Cbinom%7B5%7D%7Bk%7D*%280.25%29%5Ek*0.75%5E%7B5-k%7D%2C+k%3D3+to+5  
copy paste the link as it is not working in comments

Comment: update: I shortened it for it to work http://bit.ly/38hlPnX

Comment: Thank you this work very well .Now I'm trying to get result under a)

Comment: it also gives the correct result you mentioned 

http://bit.ly/3pajP7Y

Comment: Thanks @Sergio you are a genius!